# Where we can find the html file in our folder for the web in flutter like APK file locate in build\app\outputs\apk\debug

Tags: android, flutter, web, build

I'm new with flutter web I want to find the build web file in my folder like APK file in build folder which is installable on any device is there any file or folder for the web in our build folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a release build using release mode (flutter run --release) or by using **flutter build web**. This populates a **build/web** directory with built files, including an assets directory.

Comment: I've created build for the web but still I'm not able to find any html file in the build folder I want to run my flutter web app without android studio so how I can?

Comment: okay i see. already when you execute the build web command you get the static files in the / build / web folder, from this moment you can start your local server apache, python, or whatever you want and then redirect the server to the / build / web to see the rendering outside of android studio.

Comment: if you wish you can use this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/dhttpd) _italic_ **dhttp** package offered by the flutter documentation to visualize without android studio.

Comment: [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/web#building-the-app-for-release) **see solution here**